# Consider all possible class values for outputing the predictions on test split

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I am new to weka and i was running a Naive Bayes classifier for my multiclass classification problem.
My class is "Game" which can have multiple values like Soccer, Rugby, Cricket, Baseball etc. It has more than 20 values.
When I run NaiveBayes with the Class as "Game", i also select the option of "Output the predictions" in order to see the actual class and the missclassified class.

One of the output for that is :

inst#      actual      predicted         error           probability distribution

1         1:Soccer     5:Baseball        +               0.1  0  0   0  *0.9

Here i get the misclassified class as Baseball with a probability of 0.9 and the other class which has a probability of 0.1 is Soccer which is my correct class.
So is there a way that i can consider all the class values which has some probability and if any one of those class values match with the actual class, then it should classify it as correctly. I want the top class values in that row which has the probability values to be considered for the actual class value and if any of those class(even having the lowest probability value) match the actual class, then its the correct class.

So is it possible to get the output like this :

inst#     actual       predicted        error            probability distribution

1         1:Soccer     1:Soccer                          *1   0    0    0   0

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So just to clarify: you want to intercept the predictions of your classifier during training, check to see if the actual class has a non-zero probability / is in the 'top N classes', and then change the prediction so it says it predicted the actual class?

Comment: Yes, i want exactly the same thing! Is it possible to that?

Comment: @NBartley yes i want exactly the same thing that you interpreted. Any way to achieve that?

Comment: Are you using the GUI? I doubt that something like that is possible without programming.

Comment: @NBartley yes i am currently using the GUI. So what should be my approach?